# How to find invalid UTF-8 characters in an Oracle table column

Tags: sql, oracle, utf-8, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried the suggestions mentioned ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866626/oracle-sql-dynamic-query-non-utf-8-characters)) to check for the rows with non-utf8 characters in a column. I compared this by comparing the `LENGTH` and `LENGTHB` values of the column. However, there are around thousands of rows as such.

For one such row, the value in the column was alphanumeric with only one special character i.e. the pound symbol -> £ . (There are other records as well with the bullet listing symbol found in MS Word which come as  in Notepad++)

I used function RAWTOHEX on the column and the output did have C2A3 which is the representation of £ symbol. I'm confused as to how do I prove that it is a non-utf8 character, and on second thoughts is the method of comparing the length of the column the right way to find out?

Note:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;
----------------------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
```

PS: I am using SQL developer, but I am not an oracle developer.

Comment: What is your problem and what do you mean by "invalid UTF-8 character"?

Comment: You correctly pointed out that `C2A3` represents the `£` in UTF-8 - so what on earth do you mean by "that it is a non-utf8 character"?

Comment: Perhaps you mean non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit We are using a third party tools to capture CDC data, and the tool  generates an error if the data has non-UTF8 characters. Hence we need to identify those if present in the table. Do you know of way way how to identify them?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "non-UTF8 characters"?

Comment: I've got the same question. There are articles on invalid utf-8 data here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319022/really-good-bad-utf-8-example-test-data and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301402/example-invalid-utf8-string